# Update Google Play services. This app won't run unless you update Google Play services

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-cloud-messaging

I am currently working on Gcm for sending notifications to android device. 
I installed google play services Rev.15 from the SDK manager ->extras and imported and referenced those in my android app.
My android project API level is 17. 
In the manifest file i have

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="19"/>
```

This is the manifest of google-play-services_lib

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.google.android.gms"
    android:versionCode="4242030"
    android:versionName="4.2.42 (1018832-030)" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9"/>

</manifest>
```

I use AVD_for_Nexus_One_by_Google 4.2.2 Api level-17 Target as Google APIs(Google Inc.)

This is the code in my android app to check the play services

```
private boolean checkPlayServices() {
        int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode)) {
                GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this,
                        PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST).show();
            } else {
                Log.i(TAG, "This device is not supported.");
                finish();
            }
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

I get the following error.

Update Google Play services. This app won't run unless you update Google Play Service.

And in the log i find that, google play services is out of date. Requires 4242000 but found 3136130.

Please help me with this. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

use a real device to test Play Services related stuff.
Emulators are not guaranteed to have Google Play Services out of the box.

Comment: Thanks. I tried it with real device and its working fine. But i want to get this working with emulator as i dont have a own android device.

Comment: you probably can find a way to hack it into the emulator. But I don't believe StackOverflow is the place you'll find it. More likely a developers forum like XDA Developers.

Comment: If i get a positive reply here, that would be of much help for me. As i am spending an entire day with this. What am i doing wrong in the set up. how can i overcome that?

Comment: play services is just an .apk, like the app you're trying to create. You just need to find an up-to-date version of it (XDA developers) and install on the emulator device.